# AppAction with dependency injection

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to implement an `AppAction` in my `MAUI` application following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-actions?tabs=android).

My problem is in the implementation of the `HandleAppActions` (this is from Microsoft)

```
public static void HandleAppActions(AppAction appAction)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        var page = appAction.Id switch
        {
            "battery_info" => new SensorsPage(),
            "app_info" => new AppModelPage(),
            _ => default(Page)
        };

        if (page != null)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    });
}
```

My page has in the constructor a view model and the view model other dependencies. All of them injected. For example, here the issue

[image]

How can I call one of my pages without creating new instances of all the dependencies?

Comment: use `AddSingleton` when registering the dependency

Comment: I registered all of them as singleton

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could you provide more code about how you did dependency injection for WordEdit? And have you tried writing a constructor without parameters for WordEdit?